# svn : change commit message for selected files

Tags: svn

I was working on two differents parts of a project, and wanted to commit changes only for one part, but I made a mistake, and commited also some changes in the second part.

Now in the history revision, there are some files in the first part that have a completely irrelevant commit message. I can't change the log message, because if I do, the first part will be fixed but the second will suffer the same problem.

How can I correct my mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

You should [revert this commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo) because it contains unrelated changes and commit it properly again. This is not a problem of commit message, but of non-atomic commit.